# Can i join two tables on multiple conditions? For eg can we have two column matching after ON keyword?

Tags: sql, join

I read somewhere that there should be N-1 condition if there are N tables.? Can we join on multiple condition after ON keyword if there are only two tables.for
Eg On a.id=b.id and a.name=b.name and a.class=b.class

Comment: The answer is **Yes** .

Comment: You can put any boolean expression in the ON clause. Use AND, OR, =, >, <, LIKE etc.

Comment: You can join 2 tables and only if it's Tuesday if you wish

Comment: You can even use `on 1=1` as the condition

Comment: your example is actually spot on a.id = b.id AND a.name = b.name

Answer (score 0):

You can join on multiple condition, you can join the same table on multiple condition as well.

For example, suppose we have the following tables:

```
create table a1
(weddingTable INT(3),
 tableSeat INT(3),
 tableSeatID INT(6),
 Name varchar(10));

insert into a1
 (weddingTable, tableSeat, tableSeatID, Name)
 values (001,001,001001,'Bob'),
 (001,002,001002,'Joe'),
 (001,003,001003,'Dan'),
 (002,001,002001,'Mark');

create table a2
 (weddingTable int(3),
 tableSeat int(3),
 Meal varchar(10));

insert into a2
(weddingTable, tableSeat, Meal)
values 
(001,001,'Bob'),
(001,002,'Dan'),
(001,003,'Salmon'),
(002,001,'Steak');
```

Let's make a query example:

```
select a1.* 
from a1
inner join a2 on a1.weddingTable=a2.weddingTable
and a1.tableSeat=a2.tableSeat 
and a1.Name=a2.Meal
```

Result:

```
weddingTable    tableSeat   tableSeatID  Name
        1          1            1001      Bob
```

Check the demo for another example [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b214237d92847ce6d2e7068808d30256)

Same table Multiple join condition.

```
CREATE TABLE CORPORATE(
E_NAME VARCHAR(10),
E_ID INT,
E_DEPT VARCHAR(10),
E_LOC VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('RAM',1,'HR','DELHI');
INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('RAM',1,'SALES','DELHI');
INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('VARUN',2,'IT','BANGALORE');
INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('VARUN',2,'MARKETING','HYDERABAD');
INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('RAVI',3,'FINANCE','KOCHI');
INSERT INTO CORPORATE VALUES('RAVI',3,'FINANCE','TRIVANDRUM');

SELECT C1.E_NAME,
       C1.E_ID,
       C1.E_DEPT,
       C1.E_LOC 
FROM CORPORATE AS C1
INNER JOIN CORPORATE AS C2 ON C1.E_ID=C2.E_ID 
AND C1.E_DEPT<>C2.E_DEPT AND C1.E_LOC<>C2.E_LOC;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8bf57bd0664270d26790a07ef15eb789)

Comment: you can even join using OR clause or even CASE statements.  however be aware that you could degrade performance if the fields you are joining on are not part of an index.

Comment: @AaronReese completely agree with you, but that is a different issue

Comment: `case` _expressions_ are typically hard to optimize, even if the columns are indexed. It's generally better to use AND/OR instead.